# How can i display the video from youtube from URL using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, youtube, each

I want to read the div with class "yturl" and replace to iframe from youtube.

Why does my source code not working?

I have following source code:

HTML:

```
<div class="yturl">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwVuURFNX0E</div>
```

JS:

```
$("div.yturl").each(function(){
    var regex = /(\?v=|\&v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    var youtubeurl = $(this).text();
    var regexyoutubeurl = youtubeurl.match(regex);
    if (regexyoutubeurl) {
        $(this).html("<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+regexyoutubeurl[2]+" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because of a typo you've made.

Your code generated following html code (try to find missing quotation mark here):

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/mwVuURFNX0E frameborder=" 0"="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Corrected JavaScript code:

```
$("div.yturl").each(function(){
    var regex = /(\?v=|\&v=|\/\d\/|\/embed\/|\/v\/|\.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)/;
    var youtubeurl = $(this).text();
    var regexyoutubeurl = youtubeurl.match(regex);
    if (regexyoutubeurl) {
        $(this).html("<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+regexyoutubeurl[2]+"\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
    }
});
```

I suggest you to use Firebug or Webkit Web Inspector to see the code you generate dynamically.